# Apply filter (age, gender etc.) to pie chart in Apexcharts / React MUI - not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pie-chart, apexcharts

I have a number of charts to which I am applying a filter based on age, gender etc. It works fine with the bar chart but not for the pie chart (nor for a stacked bar but that is in a different file). This is the code I have for the pie charts:

```
const chartOptionsComparisons = merge(BaseOptionChart(), {
    tooltip: {
      marker: { show: false },
      x: {
          show: true,
          // format: 'dd MMM',
          formatter: undefined,
        title: {
          formatter: (seriesName) => seriesName,
        }
      },
      y: { 
        formatter: function(value, opts) {
             return value + ''
          },
        title: {
          formatter: (seriesName) => 'Total number of antibiotics prescribed:'
        }
      },
    },
    colors: [
      '#26734D',
      '#cc3311',

    ],
    legend: {
      show: false
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function (val) {
        return val.toFixed(0) + "%"
      },
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
          },
    plotOptions: {
       pie: {
      customScale: 0.7,
      donut: { labels: { show: false } },
      dataLabels: {
      offset: -20,
    },
    }
    },
  }); 
//calling it with return
return (
    <Card sx={{boxShadow: 'none'}}> 
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Typography variant="h4" color='#22577A'>Antibiotic Prescriptions</Typography> 
      <Typography variant="subtitle3" color='#26734D' sx={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Green Antibiotics </Typography><Typography variant='subtitle3' color='#22577a'>are  more effective, have fewer side effects and are less likely to lead to resistant infections.</Typography>
      <br />
      <Typography variant="subtitle3" color='#cc3311' sx={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Red Antibiotics </Typography><Typography variant='subtitle3' color='#22577a'>should not be used in primary care unless absolutely necessary.</Typography>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-evenly" alignItems="flex-end" spacing={3} mt={1}>
      <Box sx={{ mx: 1, width:200, height: 300 }} dir="ltr">
        <ReactApexChart type="pie" 
        series={[props.ab.practice_red, props.ab.practice_green]} 
        options={chartOptionsComparisons} 
        height={300} 
        />
      <Typography variant="subtitle2" align='center' >Your practice</Typography>     
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ mx: 1, width:200, height: 300 }} dir="ltr">
        <ReactApexChart type="pie" 
        series={[props.ab.otherpractice_red, props.ab.otherpractice_green]} 
        options={chartOptionsComparisons} 
        height={300} 
        />
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" align='center'>All practices average</Typography>
      </Box>
      </Stack>
</Card>
  );
}
//linking it to my data
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const mapState = state => ({
  ab: state.antibiotics.ab
 });
 
 const mapDispatch = ({ 
  antibiotics: {getGeneralAB}}) => ({
    getGeneralAB: () => getGeneralAB()
 });
 
 export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(AppConversionRates);
```

My data is kept in a separate file and for the moment is just fake (I will need to connect it to a data store later). This is the code in the data file:

```
let initial_state = {
  
  ab: {
    practice_green: 1000,
    otherpractice_green: 1130,
    practice_red: 960,
    otherpractice_red: 1000
}
//exporting it and linking age filters
export const antibiotics = {
    state: initial_state,

    reducers: {
      updateGeneralAB(state, payload) {

        let indexes_ages_filters =  []
        initial_state.age.categories.forEach(((cat, index)=>{
          if(payload.all_state.filters.age.includes(cat)) {
            indexes_ages_filters.push(index);
          }
        })) 

        if(indexes_ages_filters.length == 0) {
          indexes_ages_filters=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
        }

        return {
          ...state,
         
          ab: {
            practice_green: Math.round(initial_state.ab.practice_green*payload.percentage),
            otherpractice_green: Math.round(initial_state.ab.otherpractice_green*payload.percentage),
            practice_red: Math.round(initial_state.ab.practice_red*payload.percentage),
            otherpractice_red: Math.round(initial_state.ab.otherpractice_red*payload.percentage),
 }
    }

    },
    effects: (dispatch) => ({
      getGeneralAB(payload, state) {
        console.log("state", state)
        let filters = 0;
        let total_filters = 0;
        if(state.filters.age.length > 0){
          filters = filters + state.filters.age.length
          total_filters = total_filters + 7
        }
        
        if(state.filters.gender.length > 0){
          filters = filters + state.filters.gender.length
          total_filters = total_filters + 3
        }
        if(state.filters.gms.length > 0){
          filters = filters + state.filters.gms.length
          total_filters = total_filters + 2
        }
        if (filters > 0 && total_filters > 0) {
          dispatch.antibiotics.updateGeneralAB({percentage: filters/total_filters, all_state: state });
        } else {
          dispatch.antibiotics.updateGeneralAB({percentage: 1 , all_state: state});

        }
      }
    })
};
```

As it works fine for the bar chart I don't understand why it's not working for the pie.